# If Element Hasn't Changed in the last 'X' Seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element `#ChatStatus` which is constantly changing, and when a change occurs, the element slides in being visible on screen.

What I'm trying to do now is: If there hasn't occurred any changes on this element for the last 5 seconds for example, hide the element back out of the screen. Here's my code:

```
$('#ChatStatus').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $('#ChatStatus').animate({'right':'30px'},500);
});

// Now I wanna run this, when the #ChatStatus is innactive, or no changes occurred
// $('#ChatStatus').animate({'right':'-200vw'},500);
```

Here's the full project where I want to implement this inactivity feature.
https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/77hb2do0/1/

Comment: Don't use animate. Just use a CSS class for 'hidden' or 'visible' with CSS3 transitions.

Comment: Wow. DOM mutation events. That's ... those are really quite obsolete, and never widely-supported. :-) Use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead.

Comment: What updates the element? It would be good to hook this disappearing act into the thing that updates it, rather than detecting the updates from afar.

Comment: What should you use instead of DOM mutation events?

Comment: Yes, I could fire the slide effect right on the thing that updates the element, in fact, that's what I had in the first place. But I'd still have to take it out by sliding it out when inactive :\

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [this is the project](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/77hb2do0/1/) I'm trying to implement is "inactive" feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very **functional** way of doing it.  As your commenters have mentioned, this really isn't the best way of doing it; but if you want to, it's your code.

```
shouldRemove = null;
$('#ChatStatus').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    clearTimeout(shouldRemove);
    $(this).animate({'right':'30px'},500);
    shouldRemove = setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).animate({'right':'-200vw'},500);
    }.bind(this), 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very experienced with JS animation and the like, so I'll leave any question of style and method choice up to you. Aside from that, I would suggest using a global variable holding the time of the last change, and polling at regular intervals to see if that time is more than 5 seconds ago. For example:

```
var lasttime = none
$('#ChatStatus').change(function () {
    lasttime = new Date().getTime() //Set lasttime to the time when the element changed
}
setInterval(function () {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - lasttime) > 5000) { //Date().getTime() is in miliseconds,
                                                    // so 5000 for five seconds 
        $('#ChatStatus').animate({'right':'-200vw'},500);
    }
}, 1000); // Set 1000 (1 second) lower for more precision at the
          // cost of more computational time
```

I hope this helps!